# How to insert Spatial Reference in a JSON file to addFeatures on server

Tags: python, json, arcgis

I am trying to add a point using the REST API on Arcgis Enterprise on a Map Server but I do not know where to insert the spatial reference attribute piece of line.

I created a script on Python with a JSON file as the input with the attributes and geometry of the feature.

The JSON file I generated through the "Features to Json" tool on ArcMap, but I need to cancel the initial parts (see code below) otherwise it will not add the features as it gives me an error. 
This initial part contains the spatial reference information. 
The problem is that once I delete this part, I need to insert the spatial reference somewhere else. I tried inserting at the end of the code but the features are not correcly positioned. 
Does anybody know how/where I should add the piece that contains the spatial reference information on the Json File so that he can correctly position the feature? 
The script runs ok, the problem is that JSON file.

Regards,

INITIAL PART DELETED:

```
{
  "displayFieldName" : "",
  "fieldAliases" : {
    "OBJECTID" : "OBJECTID",
    "Layer" : "Layer",
    "RefName" : "RefName",
    "SETE" : "SEDE TECNICA",
    "DEF_SETE" : "DEFINIZIONE",
    "LIVELLO" : "LIVELLO",
    "SFID" : "ID"
  },
  "geometryType" : "esriGeometryPoint",
  "spatialReference" : {
    "wkid" : 32633,
    "latestWkid" : 32633
  },
  "fields" : [
    {
PART USED ON THE JSON FILE: 

[
    {
          "attributes" : {
            "OBJECTID" : 251,
            "Layer" : "RM$TXT",
            "RefName" : "ATRIO",
            "SETE" : "LO0445",
            "DEF_SETE" : "APRILIA",
            "LIVELLO" : 0,
            "SFID" : "LO0445_POI_000001"
          },
          "geometry" : {
            "x" : 303244.31379999965,
            "y" : 4607198.9022000004
          },
          "spatialReference" : {
        "wkid" : 32633,
        "latestWkid" : 32633}
        }
      ]
```

He adds the point if I cancel the line with the spatial reference code line, but obvisouly with no geographic information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [addFeatures REST API](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/add-features.htm) doesn't let you specify the incoming features spatial reference system. You can only specify the features attributes and geometry [as indicated here](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/common-data-types/feature-object.htm). You will need to convert your feature's geometry to the spatial reference you want before sending them to the API. If you're using python this can be easily done with a projection using the `arcpy` module before sending the features:

#### Using arcpy Cursors

If you get your geometry through a cursor, the `SHAPE@` field will return the geometry object which projects a `projectAs` function that allows us to project the point to the spatial reference you need.

```
#A cursor to get your data. Use SHAPE@ field to get the geometry
with arcpy.da.searchCursor(table, ["SHAPE@", ...]) as cursor:

    for item in cursor:

        # Get the PointGeometry:
        geometry = item[0]

        #Create the spatial reference you want to convert to
        spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference(102100)

        # Project the point to the spatial reference
        projected = geometry.projectAs(spatial_reference)

        # Get the point's projected location
        projected_x = projected.trueCentroid.X
        projected_y = projected.trueCentroid.Y
```

#### Without arcpy cursors

If you don't get your features through a search cursor, you need to create a [PointGeometry](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/pointgeometry.htm) feature and then follow the same steps:

```
initialSpatialReference = arcpy.SpatialReference(102100)
point = arcpy.Point(x, y)
pointGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point, initialSpatialReference)

# Now that your (x, y) is a point geometry you can project it:

#Create the spatial reference you want to convert to
spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference(3857)

# Project the point to the spatial reference
projected = pointGeometry .projectAs(spatial_reference)

# Get the point's projected location
projected_x = projected.trueCentroid.X
projected_y = projected.trueCentroid.Y
```

Then use the projected x and y values when you send the geometry's JSON to the API:

```
request = {
    features: [
        {
        attributes: {...},
        geometry: {
           x: projected_x,
           y: projected_y,
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Great answer! I modified the script and now it does the projection to web mercator before creating the Json, it is all good now. Thank you very much!